# How to addClass in jQuery to all panels

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add a CSS-Class to all primary panels. How can i do this?
This is not working:

```
$("div").find("panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');
```

html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary fixed-panel" >
            <div class="panel-heading">Strecke</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Hello I am a text
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `$("div").find(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');` missing `.` in class panel just add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select `div`. You can select `.panel-primar` directly.

```
$(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');
```

Comment: missing `.` on class `panel-primary`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div").find("panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');
```

This is not working because for 2 reason:

1. `$("div").find("panel-primary")` is not a correct selector. `panel-primary` is a invalid selector. This is the class name in yout HTML, so you have to find `.panel-primary`. So the code will be : `$("div").find(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading')`.
2. Again `$("div").find(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading')` line will search `.panel-primary` class inside a DIV element and I don't see you have a DIV outside that class.

If you have a DIV outside `.panel-primary` class element then `$("div").find(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading')` will works. If no DIV present then simply do `$(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading')`.

Hope you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

`$("div").find("panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');`

First `panel-primary`is not a valid DOM, class, ID selector.
Second your code tells that to look a DIV with a children of class `.panel-primary`.

You can simply achieve this using `$('.panel-primary').addClass('changeColorHeading')`

Or IF `.panel-primary` has a parent DIV THEN you can use `$("div").find(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');`

Answer (score 1):

Simply select pannel-primary class and

```
$(".panel-primary").addClass('changeColorHeading');
```